# Show Scale image as widget in flutter

Tags: flutter

I can show `Image` from Network url in flutter.

```
FadeInImage.assetNetwork(
        placeholder: Assets.GENRE,
        image: item.image, fit: BoxFit.cover,
      )
```

Now, I want :

- After got Image url from API,
- I'm able to Scale that image and show on UI as Widget.

I found [`ImageInfo`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/ImageInfo-class.html) had attribute is `scale`

But I didn't get any example details how to apply this.

People who know,

Please give me an example,

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Image.Network as it's having scale and BoxFit both options. check out Image.Network [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Image/Image.network.html).

Example:

```
FadeInImage(
  placeholder: Assets.GENRE,
  image: Image.Network(url,scale:2.0,fit:BoxFit.cover,repeat:ImageRepeat.noRepeat),
)
```